# Sql Join Subquery output in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm write some SQL query with join and sub query i want convert into linq

```
 select a.CampaignId, a.ImagePath,(select Count(a1.CampaignId) from INN_Customers_Campaigns_Images a1 where a1.CampaignId = a.CampaignId)ImageCount from INN_Customers_Campaigns_Images a
inner join INN_Customers_Gallary b  On b.CampaignId = a.CampaignId  and a.CreatedBy = b.CustomerId
```

Comment: You have to give more information. What is your model?

Comment: public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CampaignId { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string IsPrimary { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModofiedDate { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public int ImageCount { get; set; }

Comment: You can edit your question to make your code readable

Answer (score 0):

You can use let clause for your sub query

```
   var result = from a in context.INN_Customers_Campaigns_Images
   join b in context.INN_Customers_Gallary  on new { a.CampaignId , a.CreatedBy } equals new { b.CampaignId , b.CustomerId }
    let imageCount = context.INN_Customers_Campaigns_Images.Where(a1 => a1.CampaignId == a.CampaignId).Count()
   select new 
   {
       a.CampaignId,
       a.ImagePath
       ImageCount = imageCount
    }
```

Comment: @tinku [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)